# Laraver8: Fullcalendar ver3 add and edit event feature

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar, laravel-8

I am trying to create a calendar with "add event" and "edit event" feature using Fullcalendar.

The problem is that I am able to edit events with the codes shown below but I can't add new events.  After I hit the Add Event button the browser doesn't show any errors, it just shows a whit blank. I was able to add new events before I changed the codes to add the "edit event" feature.

**calendar.blade.php**

```html
<body>
        <div id="dialog">
            <div id="dialog-body">
                <form id="dayClick" method="post" action="{{route('eventStore')}}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Event Title</label>
                        <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Event Title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Start Date/Time</label>
                        <input type="text" id="start" class="form-control" name="start" placeholder="Start date & time">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>End Date/Time</label>
                        <input type="text" id="end" class="form-control" name="end" placeholder="End date & time">
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="eventId" name="event_id">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="update">Add Event</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: true,
                displayEventTime: false,
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today ',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'myCustomButton'
                },
                events: "{{route('allEvent')}}",
                dayClick: function(date, event, view) {
                    $('#start').val(date);
                    $('#dialog').dialog({
                        title: 'Add Event',
                        width: 600,
                        height: 600,
                        modal: true,
                    })
                },
                select: function(start, end) {
                    $('#start').val(start);
                    $('#end').val(end);
                    $('#dialog').dialog({
                        title: 'Add Event',
                        width: 600,
                        height: 600,
                        modal: true,
                    })
                },
                eventClick: function(event) {
                    $('#title').val(event.title);
                    $('#start').val(event.start);
                    $('#end').val(event.end);
                    $('#eventId').val(event.id);
                    $('#update').html('Update');
                    $('#dialog').dialog({
                        title: 'Edit Event',
                        width: 600,
                        height: 600,
                        modal: true,
                    })
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

**web.php**

```php
Route::post('store', [TestController::class, 'store'])->name('eventStore');
```

**TestController.php**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            if (!empty($request->event_id)) {
                $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'title' => 'required',
                    'start' => 'required',
                    'end' => 'required'
                ]);
                if ($validator->failed()) {
                    return redirect()->back();
                } else {
                    if (empty($request->event_id)) {
                        Event::create($request->all());
                        return redirect()->back();
                    } else {
                        Event::where('id', $request->event_id)->update([
                            'title' => $request->title,
                            'start' => $request->start,
                            'end' => $request->end
                        ]);
                        return redirect()->back();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

I think there's something wrong in the Controller but I couldn't figure out.
Any help or advice would be appreciated as I have tried multiple methods with no success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My controller has separate functions for store and create. Maybe try this tutorial and see if you can get closer to what you're looking for:
https://www.positronx.io/create-events-in-laravel-using-fullcalendar-and-jquery-ajax/